# What exception does Security.stripInaccessible throw?

Tags: apex, security, field-level-security

This [new security method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Security.htm) `Security.stripInaccessible` both strips out fields that the user has no rights to and will throw an exception if the object-level permissions are being violated.

What exception type is thrown (so I can catch and handle that specific type)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a **`System.NoAccessException`**. The message is:

> No access to entity: MyObject__c

Not sure the easiest way to verify, but I set up a Visualforce Page with the below controller so the running user didn't need appropriate permissions to execute anonymous Apex.

```
public with sharing class Demo
{
    public String type { get; private set; }
    public String message { get; private set; }
    public Demo()
    {
        try
        {
            Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.CREATABLE, new List<NoPerm__c> {
                new NoPerm__c()
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            message = e.getMessage();
            type = e.getTypeName();
        }
    }
}
```

And the markup was simply:

```
<apex:page controller="Demo">
    <apex:pageMessage severity="FATAL"
                      summary="{!type}"
                      detail="{!message}" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks, not in a position to test today and couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: Yeah, dunno if it's in the docs.

Comment: +1 Same thing that I did, you were just two minutes faster!

Comment: @sfdcfox I guess I've still got it!

Comment: @KeithC The docs almost never tell you what exceptions can be thrown. It's one of the most annoying aspects of the docs.